# Realm Swift use locally only, however it still tries to connect online

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am following the [realm swift getting started guide here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) and it is working fine. I have the following object:

```
class Dog: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
  dynamic var age = 0
}
```

and in my viewcontroller I have

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)

    let myDog = Dog()
    myDog.name = "Rex"
    myDog.age = 1

    let realm = try! Realm()

    try! realm.write {
      realm.add(myDog)
    }
}
```

little snitch reports that realm tries to connect to `static.realm.io` and `api.mixpanel.com`. How do I stop realm from attempting to connect to various servers if I only want to use it locally?

Comment: Please include more code, only from this context we cannot tell what might be "wrong". Are you sure you didn't set up a connection to a Realm Object Server? If you were only using a Realm schema with a local configuration, this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I added all the code encompassing the problem.

Comment: You missed the most important part. Please show the code where you set up your Realm configuration.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I don't set up any Realm configuration; this is it.

Comment: Where and how is fileURL stored?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's intended behavior.

> Realm collects anonymous analytics when your app is run with a debugger attached, or when it runs in a simulator.

Please see our doc for more details.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#i-see-a-network-call-to-mixpanel-when-i-run-my-app-what-is-that

It doesn't happen in a release build. To prevent this even in debug build, set environment variable named `REALM_DISABLE_ANALYTICS`.

See also https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMAnalytics.mm#L37-L44