# get output frames failed, state 8196

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

When I try to customise a tableView cell, I found this error.

> "Get output frames failed, state 8196"

I just have no idea it is the error from realm or from my customise tableView cell.

```
class StudentTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var student: Results<StudentName>?
    var selectedClass: ClassName? {
        didSet {
            load()
        }
    }
    var selected: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.title = selected
        tableView.register(StudentTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "studentName")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return student?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "studentName", for: indexPath) as! StudentTableViewCell
        cell.name.text = student?[indexPath.row].name ?? "There are no student in this class"
        cell.number.text = "\(student?[indexPath.row].studentNumber ?? 0)"
        return cell
    }
    func load() {
        student = selectedClass?.studentNames.sorted(byKeyPath: "studentNumber", ascending: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I think it did work when I am using Xcode 9 and Swift 4.1 but now in Xcode 10 it doesn't since it only show me this error and whole blank page of table view.

Comment: Are you using a Storyboard? Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: yes tableview storyboard

Comment: Where's the network call?  "Get output frames" refers to a BoringSSL method: `nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames`

Answer (score 2):

This error can be printed in the console when you use Realm even when you intend to only use it offline.

When the app is run in debug mode it will anonymously collect analytics, as stated in this answer: [Realm Swift use locally only, however it still tries to connect online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784877/realm-swift-use-locally-only-however-it-still-tries-to-connect-online/45800268#45800268)

To stop the error, click edit scheme, and add the environment variable `REALM_DISABLE_ANALYTICS`, and set it to `YES` as shown:

[Environment variable screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VZys.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Storyboard, you should not call `tableView.register`, you should simply set the `reuseIdentifier` for your prototype cell in storyboard.

Comment: how and where do i set this please?

Comment: @JoanneFsadni in the storyboard, where you add prototype cells to your table view.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate .xib file for the cell, you should use:

```
tableView.register(nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)
```

In other words the registration of your cell would be something like that:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "your cell nib name", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "your cell identifier")
```

If you have placed your cell in the tableview inside the controller that sits in the Storyboard then you do not need to register your cell, and as @Dávid Pásztor mentioned make sure you add the cell identifier to the cell in the Storyboard